# Glut, different context in different thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, freeglut

I'm trying to have to different glut window in different context, I mean, each window have its own callback for display, idle...

So I've some problems about glut:

First attempt:

glutInit at the beginning of the programme, thread after ->
  When I close a window, an error occurred :

```
freeglut  ERROR:  Internal <Event Handler> function called without first calling 'glutInit'.
```

Second attempt:

glutInit in each thread:
When the second thread is lauched:

```
freeglut illegal glutInit() reinitialization attempt
```

Comment: `differents glut window in differents context` -> I do not understand what does it actually mean. Explain clearly what is the design. How many threads do you have? How many windows? How many thread actually calls OpenGL routines?

Comment: I have 2 threads (in addition to the main thread). Each represents a context : A windows, callbacks, and glutMainLoop()

Comment: AFAIK, GLUT and multiple threads don't go together. See e.g. the [documentation for `glutMainLoop`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html#SECTION00041000000000000000): "This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program." You might have more luck with a more modern library like GLFW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GLUT** has not been designed in thread safety in mind (or even multiple threads support at all). So I am afraid, that with GLUT you won't be able to achieve what you want. However, GLFW seems to be much better in this matter:

> **Thread safety**
>
> Most GLFW functions may only be called from the main thread, but some
>   may be called from any thread. However, no GLFW function may be called
>   from any other thread until GLFW has been successfully initialized on
>   the main thread, including functions that may called before
>   initialization.
>
> The reference documentation for every GLFW function states whether it
>   is limited to the main thread.
>
> The following categories of functions are and will remain limited to
>   the main thread due to the limitations of one or several platforms:
>
> - Initialization and termination
> - Event processing
> - Creation and destruction of window, context and cursor objects

This part seems quite important in your case:

> Rendering may be done on any thread. The following context related
>   functions may be called from any thread:
>
> - glfwMakeContextCurrent
> - glfwGetCurrentContext
> - glfwSwapBuffers
> - glfwSwapInterval
> - glfwExtensionSupported
> - glfwGetProcAddress
>
> [...]
>
> GLFW uses no synchronization objects internally except for
>   thread-local storage to keep track of the current context for each
>   thread. Synchronization is left to the application.

Source: [GLFW Doc - Thread Safety](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro.html#thread_safety)